# MaTeX in the labels

Tags: plotting, labeling, matex

Writing

```
Plot[Sin[2.5 x], {x, 0, 2}, PlotLabel -> Framed["a=1.5" // MaTeX]]
```

I get the expected labeled plot:

[image]

However, if I just change `1.5` in the label to `2.5`:

```
Plot[Sin[2.5 x], {x, 0, 2}, PlotLabel -> Framed["a=2.5" // MaTeX]]
```

I get

[image]

What may be the problem here and how to solve it?

Comment: Quitting and restarting the kernel got rid of this behavior. Yet, what may have caused in the first place?

Comment: It looks like your system's temporary directory got cleared out for some reason, breaking your running MaTeX session. MaTeX expects its temporary files to persist throughout the session. This has nothing to do with you changing `1.5` to `2.5`. You can reset MaTeX's temporary directory by re-loading the package with ``Get["MaTeX`"]`` (no kernel restart needed but make sure you use `Get` and not `Needs`).

Comment: @Szabolcs : Thank you for your comment. But why was MaTeX OK with `1.5` and not with `2.5` in the labels?

Comment: As I said, it has nothing to do with that. As you yourself said, it happened only once and you can't reproduce it. If you _can_ consistently reproduce it, then something would be wrong (please let me know in that case)

Comment: I still don't get it. If the MaTeX session got broken at some point, why was MaTeX working **after that**, repeatedly, with `1.5` but not with `2.5`?

Comment: Now I understand. That's because MaTeX caches results. It did not need to run LaTeX again (and it did not need to work with the temporary directory) to get a result that it has already computed recently.

Comment: Do you have any idea about why the temporary directory may have gotten cleared? Did you do it manually? Do you have any special "cleanup" software that does it for you automatically from time to time? As far as I'm aware, Windows shouldn't do this automatically (but I may be wrong).

Comment: As I recall, MaTeX was working repeatedly, in different commands, with `1.5` but not with `2.5`. However, that recollection may be faulty, and now I cannot reproduce this behavior. However, I can say that I did not clear the temporary directory manually, and I am aware of having any special software that does it automatically.

Comment: If this persists (e.g. a "helpful" antivirus software keeps clearing `%TEMP%`), then you can permanently (!) set MaTeX's working directory to a fixed location using the `"WorkingDirectory"` setting of `ConfigureMaTeX`. See the documentation of `ConfigureMaTeX`. If you find a reproducible failure mode, pls contact me with precise steps to trigger it (preferably email).

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments. A similar behavior has occurred again, and `Get["MaTeX`"]` did help. I have now set a permanent MaTeX working directory. This should hopefully resolve the matter. Would you like to post your comments as an answer, so that I could formally accept it?